# How to use bitwise operators in JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api, bitwise-and

I am using JPA CriteriaBuilder, and List for querying user table. I need to use bitwise & operator in CriteriaBuilder. My sample code base is as follows.

User table structure is as follows.

```
create TABLE `tbl_user` (
    `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `login_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    `role_value` INTEGER,
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Here `role_value` is the field where we are specifying bitwise OR values to keep the role of the user.

Roles are specified with below bit values

```
public enum Role {

    ROLE_POLICE(1, "POLICE"),
    ROLE_BRIDGE(2, "BRIDGE"),

    ROLE_SECURITY(4, "SECURITY"),
    ROLE_ASSISTANT_USER(8, "ASSISTANT_USER"),
    ROLE_HARDWARE_USER(16, "HARDWARE_USER"),
    ;

    private final String roleValue;
    private final Integer id;

    Role(Integer id, String roleValue, Role... secondaryRoles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.roleValue = roleValue;
        this.secondaryRoles = secondaryRoles;
    }

}
```

I would like to query user list using CriteriaBuilder, where i need to filter users with certain roleValues using "Predicate" and JPA "Expressions".

My code is as follows.

```
@Override
public Page<UserView> listUsers(UserListRequest userListRequest) {


    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> listCriteria = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userRoot = listCriteria.from(User.class);

    if (!userListRequest.getUserIds().isEmpty()) {
        wherePredicates.add(cb.in(userRoot.get("id")).value(userListRequest.getUserIds()));
    }

    /* this portion is having syntax error */
    if (null != userListRequest.getRoleValue()) {
        wherePredicates.add(cb.equal(userRoot.get("role_value"), (userRoot.get("role_value") & userListRequest.getRoleValue()));
    }   

    .
    .
    .
    return getPageFromTypedQuery(cb, userRoot, listCriteria, wherePredicates, userListRequest, UserView.class);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK JPA does not support bitwise operators, sorry.

Comment: How did you map the enum? Please show your User entity

Comment: Hi @Simon, 

Enum is not mapped in entity. One user can have multiple roles. So based on user's roles, we will calculate the role_value for the user. (bitwise OR operation).

Entity column is mapped using Column mapping only. 

@Column(name = "role_value")
private Integer roleValue;

Comment: In that case you simply have to calculate the value by yourself and pass it to equal

Comment: User can have multiple roles. If a user is havng roles "SECURITY" and "ASSISTANT_USER", then his role_value field will be having value = 12 (ie, 4 | 8 = 12).

If i need user with role "SECURITY", if i use equals method, it will not fech the record. I need to call the following query for this. (SELECT * FROM tbl_user where role_value & 4 = 4).

Comment: @Unni did you manage to get the answer for this? I'm trying to get the solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible to implement your own expression and use it. See BinaryArithmeticOperation for example.